# kill query while in status 'system lock' won't finish

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a query loading data infile writing into a mysql 5.6 database. When I kill the query, it will just stuck there showing 'killed' but 'system lock', for ever.

I checked 'show engine innodb status' it says the thread 'not start'.

I've been stuck for this problem for a long time, anything would be helpful. Really appreciate it.

http://cl.ly/image/3f140L1H1i1x